# Absolutely positioned psuedo element scrolls with parent

Tags: css

I have a table that is too wide on mobile and stretches off screen. I therefore allow the parent of this to be horizontally scrolled so that a user can still see the content. I am trying to add a slight gradient to the right of the container to indicate that there is more content there like this:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wide {width:1000px;}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,000000+100&0+0,0.64+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.64) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.64) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.64) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001e5799', endColorstr='#a3000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div wide">
    <p>dfsakf djfsdklfskld fds fsduj fh ghj gy jhuyuy gu jhg hg jhgjh gjh g hjgjh h gjh gjh ghjgh g hjgjh g jhg jh ghj gh g jhg jhg hg j</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when a user scrolls, the psuedo element moves, and is no longer in the 
correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to set the gradient to the `parent`, and this will prevent it from scrolling:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 95%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) calc(100% - 15px), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64) 100%);
}
.wide {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div wide">
      <p>dfsakf djfsdklfskld fds fsduj fh ghj gy jhuyuy gu jhg hg jhgjh gjh g hjgjh h gjh gjh ghjgh g hjgjh g jhg jh ghj gh g jhg jhg hg j</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**If you want to use a pseudo element...**

If the parent height is not dynamic, you can change the `position` of the pseudo element to `fixed`, and set a fixed height to it.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wide {width:1000px;}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 70px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,000000+100&0+0,0.64+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.64) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.64) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.64) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001e5799', endColorstr='#a3000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div wide">
    <p>dfsakf djfsdklfskld fds fsduj fh ghj gy jhuyuy gu jhg hg jhgjh gjh g hjgjh h gjh gjh ghjgh g hjgjh g jhg jh ghj gh g jhg jhg hg j</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another pseudo element solution is to wrap the `parent` in another div (`.wrapper` in the example), and use it as a container for the pseudo element:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wide {
  width: 1000px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative; 
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,000000+100&0+0,0.64+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#001e5799', endColorstr='#a3000000', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="div wide">
      <p>dfsakf djfsdklfskld fds fsduj fh ghj gy jhuyuy gu jhg hg jhgjh gjh g hjgjh h gjh gjh ghjgh g hjgjh g jhg jh ghj gh g jhg jhg hg j</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome :) That was an interesting question.